# cDetailview Display alias name yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-widgets

My view code

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
                    'data'=>$model,
                    'attributes'=>array(
                        'id',
                        'eventstype',
                        'visibility',
                        'enable',
                    ),
                )); ?>
```

controller code

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = ManageEventsType::model()->findByAttributes(array("id" => $id));
                if($model){
                $this->render("view", array(
                    "model" => $model
                ));
                }
    }
```

in my view page the records display like following

```
Id          3
Eventstype  Holiday
Visibility  2
Enable      0
```

i want to display visibility as enable or disable . 1- enable , 2- Disable ,
any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = $model->visibility == 1 ? 'enable' : 'disabled';

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'eventstype',
    array(
       'name' => 'visibility',
       'value' => $text,
    ),

    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: nice answer tinybyte , one more doubt if visibility have 2 more values , i mean 1-Enable , 2- Disable , 3- Inactive then

Comment: then use `switch()` on it :D

Answer (score 0):

The 'elegant' way to do this is to change your ActiveRecord model.

```
class ManageEventsType extends CActiveRecord
{

   /* Give it a name that is meaningful to you */
   public $visibility_text;

   ...

}
```

This will extend your model by creating an additional attribute.

Inside your model, you then add (and overwrite) the afterFind() function.

```
class ManageEventsType extends CActiveRecord    
{
    public $visibility_text;
    protected function afterFind ()
    {
        $this->visibility_text =  (($this->visibility) == 1)? 'enabled' : 'disabled');
        parent::afterFind ();   // Call the parent's version as well
    }

    ...
}
```

This will effective give you a new field, so you can do something like :

```
$eventTypeModel = ManageEventsType::model()->findByPK($eventTypeId);
echo 'The visibility is .'$eventTypeModel->visibility_text;
```

So you final code will look like this.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
                    'data'=>$model,
                    'attributes'=>array(
                        'id',
                        'eventstype',
                        'visibility_text',     // <== show the new field ==> //
                        'enable',
                    ),
                ));
?>
```